# Approving / editing low quality answers

Tags: discussion

So I edited this answer after going through the review section: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102478/4525

First impressions were that the language was pretty poor and it appeared to be a pretty weak answer overall, however it is not breaking the rules.

What should we be doing with posts like this? Edit to polish a turd, or recommend deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That answer does not break any rule, and it's perfectly fine that it will remain. One of the nice things about the system here is that good answers float up, so having a few bad answers at the bottom is not really an issue.

You're welcome, however, to

- Edit it to increase its quality, if you have the time and patience. Your edit in this case is great.
- Downvote it if it is not useful or shows little to no effort.

Comment: Cool thanks Sir Oak!